# Building a FULLTEXT search SQL Native Query in Spring Data JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, full-text-search

I need to build a custom Native Query to perform a FULLTEXT Search in MySql Database.
The query I need to run is something like

```
“SELECT * FROM items where match(name) against('+bag +white' IN BOOLEAN MODE);”
```

This query needs to search all the items in items table that have both "White" and "Bag" keywords in the name column.

The problem I am having is the keyword parameter that I’m receiving in the Get Method is a single String like “White Bag” or “Bag White”.
So I need to split the keyword String by a space “ “ and add a plus (+) sign in each word and make a custom native query with String Builder or somethingu. Can you tell me how do I achieve this? Is there a Spring Data specific way of doing it?

Comment: Is it possible this is purely a Java string-manipulation question? Do you want to know how to change the string `"Bag White"` into the string `"+bag +white"` ? Please [edit] your question to explain more fully.

Comment: No that I know. I want to know how to run this native query (built by the string manupulation) in the repository file.